# in react-chartjs-2 last value, if is 4 digit or greater then its cropping the value

Tags: react-chartjs-2

in react-chartjs-2 last value, if is 4 digit or greater then its cropping the value.
and I am attaching image and my code.

I want to show all the digits even if its greater than 4 digits

[image: chart image]

this is my chart component look like

````
<Component
          data={chartData}
          plugins={[ChartDataLabels]}
          options={{
            plugins: {
              datalabels: {
                color: theme.colorScheme !== 'dark' ? theme.colors.gray[9] : theme.colors.gray[0],
                anchor: 'end',
                offset: -20,
                align: 'start',
                fontSize: 18,
                clip: false, // if true will mask the values if goes out of the chart
              },
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: ' ',
              },
              legend: {
                display: false,
              },
            },
            scales: {
              y: {
                grid: {
                  color: theme.colorScheme !== 'dark' ? theme.colors.gray[4] : theme.colors.gray[8],
                },
                ticks: {
                  color: theme.colorScheme !== 'dark' ? theme.colors.dark[6] : theme.colors.gray[5],
                  font: {
                    size: 16,
                  },
                  beginAtZero: true,
                },
              },
              x: {
                grid: {
                  color: theme.colorScheme !== 'dark' ? theme.colors.gray[4] : theme.colors.gray[8],
                },
                ticks: {
                  color: theme.colorScheme !== 'dark' ? theme.colors.dark[5] : theme.colors.gray[5],
                  font: {
                    size: 14,
                  },
                  beginAtZero: true,
                },
              },
            },
          }}
        />
    ```
````